# Rails Heroku loading part of the background image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku, background, assets

I have a rails app on Heroku. In this app I have background images and I call them as;

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('<%= asset_path ('4.jpg') %>');">
```

The background images working but suddenly, it started showing some part of them.

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening? Realized that also happens for the main page carousel slider bakground images. But when I check background link, it shows the full picture but image not loading on slider.

Comment: Are they both referring to the same URL?

Comment: Seems I took the wrong url in div class. But the image is shown like above. These are static pictures. Why it would appear like this?. I have been considering using and trying to understand Elastic Beanstalk. But there are couple issues like db migrate, sending emails etc.. Heroku is easier, I am trying to understand which is better

Comment: That should be related to network problems when you were downloading them the first time. Try to force refresh your browser cache using `CTRL+R`.

Comment: I have commit and pushed to heroku and started working again

Answer (score 0):

Try to use image_tag. Here is an example with an image located in app/assets/images

```
<div class="fill">
    <%= image_tag("4")%>
</div>
```